# I can not start xterm anymore under Cygwin + Xming under Win 7

Tags: cygwin, xterm, xorg, xming

I am using Cygwin under Windows 7 with Xming. I can not start xterm anymore, although I was able to do it previously on the same installation. Xming is running. DISPLAY variable is set to localhost:0.0. When I try to start xterm, I get:

```
user@TMB070 ~
$ xterm
Warning: Cannot convert string "-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion
xterm: cannot load font '-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1'
      0 [main] xterm 6476 child_info_fork::abort: data segment start: parent(0x3BE000) != child(0x32E000)
xterm: Error 29, errno 11: Resource temporarily unavailable
Reason: spawn: fork() failed
```

I think the last time I used xterm when it was still working, I maybe tried to change the font, maybe this is related.

How can I get xterm running again?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like xterm is trying to load a font that doesn't exist on your system, you can either add the font, or tell xterm to not load it but use another.

How did you try to change the font? Try to undo that.

Usually an XApp will load resources from $HOME/.XDefaults. Did you edit this file and change any resources for XTerm?

You can also see how to [load XMing fonts](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/fonts.php). It's possible you had it running before on an older server that had extra fonts that you currently do not have.