# start X window applications with Cygwin+Xming or CygwinX on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, xming, cygwin-x

I followed the instructions from previous posts on superuser to try and install cygwin including xorg-server as well as trying the alternative of bringing up X windows using Xming (including [setting up](https://superuser.com/questions/389629/i-can-not-start-xterm-anymore-under-cygwin-xming-under-win-7) the [fonts](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/fonts.php)), but I can't get any X windows to show up from my cygwin console:

```
$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display:
```

I tried with emacs, but only opens as `emacs -nw` would do.

Even though I installed xorg-server (and everything else under the xorg-* section), I don't seem to have startxwin installed:

```
$ startxwin
-bash: startxwin: command not found
```

Any ideas? Could it be related to security issues like an antivirus software or something?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to set your DISPLAY variable to tell Xorg where to display, try:

> $ DISPLAY=:0.0 xeyes

`:0.0` is the default display of Xming, you may need to change it accourding to your Xming parameters

Answer (score 1):

Install the xinit package in cygwin to get startxwin.

Comment: I did but still doesn't let me have any X windows...

Comment: Same here while using the experimental cygwin packages.  Using the stable ones works for me.